# How can i read a file from iCloud in an iOS-device with cordova?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, filepicker, cordova-plugin-file

I want to read the content of a PDF file stored in iCloud.

1. I pick the file with the FilePicker Phonegap iOS Plugin (https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin).
   The plugin gives me the temporary path where the file is copied.
2. I want to read it whith the Cordova File Plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)
   but I did something wrong and the log is always giving me an error.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.successCallback = function (path) {
    var fileName = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var fileDir = path.substr(0,path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    console.log("FilePath: " + path);

    $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(fileDir, fileName)
      .then(function (data) {
          var index = data.indexOf("base64,");
          if(index > 0)
          {
              data = data.substr(index+7);
          }
          console.log("Data OK=" + data);
      }, function (error) {
          console.log("Error reading file: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      });                 
}
window.FilePicker.pickFile($scope.successCallback, $scope.errorCallback);
```

And that's the output:

```
$FilePath: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/22E33EF4-832B-4911-92A6-312927C42A7C/tmp/DocumentPickerIncoming/file.pdf
$Error reading file: {"code":5,"message":"ENCODING_ERR"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized that in the *File Path* was a "tmp" folder.

According of this, I changed the "fileDir" in order to matching the *cordova.file properties map to physical paths on a real device* which is referred in the *iOS File System Layout* of the documentation of cordova-plugin-file.

Now it works :)

Here is the final code:

```
$scope.successCallback = function (path) {
var fileName = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var fileDir = cordova.file.tempDirectory + "DocumentPickerIncoming/";

console.log("FilePath: " + path);

$cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(fileDir, fileName)
  .then(function (data) {
      var index = data.indexOf("base64,");
      if(index > 0)
      {
          data = data.substr(index+7);
      }
      console.log("Data OK=" + data);
      }, function (error) {
          console.log("Error reading file: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      });             
}
window.FilePicker.pickFile($scope.successCallback, $scope.errorCallback);
```